# Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [403] in GCP for Firebase Management Api

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-platform

i am try to create a new project using resourcemanager.projects.create But got an error like :(

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [403]
Errors [
    Message[Request had insufficient authentication scopes.] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]
]
```

Can anyone please tell me What i am doing wrong.
Here is my code :

```
private async void GoogleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var cr = new PromptCodeReceiver();

        var result = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        new ClientSecrets { ClientId = GoogleClientId,ClientSecret = GoogleSecretKey },
            new[] { "email", "profile" },
                "user",
                 CancellationToken.None);

        if (result.Token.IsExpired(SystemClock.Default))
        {
            await result.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);
        }

        CloudResourceManagerService cloudResourceManagerService = new CloudResourceManagerService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = GetCredential(result.Token.AccessToken, FirebaseAuthType.Google),
            ApplicationName = "Kapiling",
            //ApiKey = "apikey"
        });

        // TODO: Assign values to desired properties of `requestBody`:
        Data.Project requestBody = new Data.Project();
        requestBody.Name = "TESTING";
        requestBody.ProjectNumber = 415104041262;
        requestBody.ProjectId = "tokyo-rain-123";
        requestBody.CreateTime = "2014-10-02T15:01:23.045123456Z";

        ProjectsResource.CreateRequest request = cloudResourceManagerService.Projects.Create(requestBody);

}
```

I am try to access using public static GoogleCredential FromAccessToken(string accessToken, IAccessMethod accessMethod = null); method

```
public static GoogleCredential GetCredential(string accessToken, FirebaseAuthType authType)
    {
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken(accessToken, null);
        return credential;
    }
```

**Thanks for everyone who help me i Solved this issues.
Thanks again. :)**

Comment: Have you enabled organizations for your Google Cloud Platform account? Next you are not requesting scopes including `resourcemanager.projects.create` or `roles/owner`

Answer (score 1):

This trouble is caused by incorrect scopes of authorization, that's correct. The solution for this particular case is to authorize only once with correct scopes(preferred) or to authorize at every such situation when you need to write/update/append.

However, the author only commented that the problem is solved but not described the solution. In many cases which guided by official API documentation, you can see this code

```
            const string credPath = "token.json";
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker
                .AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true))
                .Result;
```

In those examples, you're specifying the last parameter to save some auth data to the folder defined by the credPath variable. Note that if you want to change your scopes after you run the app once, this auth data won't be overwritten so you have to:

1. delete this existing data every time before running the app
2. change credPath
3. or simply remove this parameter, but in this case, you'll have to confirm your auth every time you start the app.

Comment: Thank you! I changed my scope from `ReadOnly` to `ReadWrite` and could not understand why I was still getting that error. Deleting `token.json` solved it!

Answer (score 1):

You first have to set your scope to Calendar (as this is the one with most permissions, you also have: CalendarEvents, CalendarEventsReadonly, CalendarReadonly,CalendarSettingsReadonly choose which one you need depending on your needed permission level) like this :

```
        static string[] Scopes = {CalendarService.Scope.Calendar};
```

But this is not done, as you need to delete your credentials path that was already created or change its name , in the documentation his name was "token.json" as if you leave this one the user had already agreed on specific access to his data but now if you delete this file or changed he'll be prompted to a new window on his browser to accept the new access to his data (in the case of Scope.Calendar scope, he'll be prompted to accept that we have the right to get, insert, update and delete his events on his calendar among others)

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the GCP documentation, it seems like you (also) need the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` scope. See https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/authorizing

Comment: Hello @FrankvanPuffelen i already give access for authorize apikey. But Nothing word but i try again.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change your code for `GetCredential()`. Note: I am not sure what you are trying to do with `FirebaseAuthType` so I have left `authType` as an unused parameter.

```
public static GoogleCredential GetCredential(string accessToken, FirebaseAuthType authType)
    {
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken(accessToken, null);
// The following line is no longer needed
//      credential = credential.CreateScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform");
        return credential;
    }
```

[EDIT]: Additional code to change due to the comment `createScopedRequired = false`

You received this message because you already authenticated with scopes. To change the scopes requires another authorization. In this case request the correct scopes. Note, you do not need the other scopes (email and profile). Put them back in later if you do.

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform" };

var result = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    new ClientSecrets {
        ClientId = GoogleClientId,
        ClientSecret = GoogleSecretKey },
    scopes,
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

Comment: Hello @johnHanley i got **IcreateScopedRequired = false** Is this effect anything ??

Comment: See the new changes to my answer. I explained what this message means and the additional code. Also note I commented out my first suggestion.